# Python 3.7: Inheriting list, abstract ignored

Tags: python, list, abstract

The following does not raise:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
class Test(list, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def test(self):
        pass
test = Test()
```

although this does:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
class Test(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def test(self):
        pass
test = Test()
```

Is this a known problem? What can I do to fix it? I need to inherit from something that looks exactly like a list and create an abstract inheritor. Thank you.

Comment: I wanted to post it in Python3.7 issue tracker, but I want to find a better way to write this first. If anyone can come up with an idea...

Comment: It's probably worth raising in the issue tracker; if nothing else, the reason *why* it doesn't work should probably be more clearly documented. It *seems* that the restriction is on making subclasses of built-in types abstract; remember that Python-the-language doesn't really have abstract classes; the `abc` library just simulates them. There may be something about how built-ins are implemented that precludes the library from working with them. (Although it must be more subtle than that, since *everything* inherits from the built-in class `object`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you should not inherit directly from`list`. There are some wrapper classes for doing this in `collections`. In this case [`UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList):

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from collections import UserList
class Test(UserList, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def test(self):
        pass
test = Test()
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/HorribleAuthenticInterface) from:

```
class Test1(Test):
  def test(self):
    print("foo")

test = Test1()
test.append(10)
test.test()
print(test)
```

Results:

```
foo
[10]
```

Comment: I'd never heard of user list before: +1

Comment: There is **UserDict** and  **UserString** also, they are the way to subclass from "built-in" objects